# Iphone App contract-Entering Bank Details

Tags: iphone

I have just got registered with iphone Dev program. in Itunes Connect,I only get FREE APPS contract. How can I enter Bank details before uploading any App?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to go to your iTunes connect
   account.
2. click on 'Contracts, Tax, & Banking Information' link
3. you will then have a page with 'Request New Contracts' & 'Your Contracts In Effect'
4. check the one that says 'Paid Applications' and submit and continue from there.

You will need your full bank information with things like the ABA routing number and the SWIFT number for your bank. Your bank will provide all this for you if you have not got it. The details may vary from country to country depending on the banking laws.

Also it can take some time for the information to be processed by Apple so do it well in advance of releasing any paid apps so you don't get a delay.

In this contracts area you can also sign up for th an iAds account as well.

Comment: I only see a single entry of FREE APPLICATIONS. There is no link of request new contracts!

Comment: then you need to fill out the free application and get that approved as that will give Apple all the basic information they need about you. When that is approved then it will enable the addition of paid apps and iAd.

Comment: Do you mean that I submit my first app as FREE then change it to paid app?

Comment: have you actually registered and paid your $99 and been approved by Apple to submit free apps? because if you have then you should be able to see the 'upgrade' to paid apps and iAd. If you have applied and been approved and cannot see the upgrade then you probably need to contact Apple and tell them about the problem